# Of scraping data, headless browsers, and Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

So i'm a CS student trying to learn web scraping and all the do's and dont's that come along with it. After messing about with iMacros and a few other data scraping 'tools', I turned to Python, a language I was not familiar with at the time. I learned about BeautifulSoup and urllib2, and blundered my way through learning it through stackoverflow and a few other forums.

Now, using the knowledge ive gained so far, I can scrape most static web pages. However, we all know that the era of static pages is over, as JS reigns supreme on even mediocre websites now.

I would like someone to please guide me in the right direction here. I want to learn a method to load Javascript-laden webpages, load all the content, and then somehow get this data into the BeautifulSoup function. Urllib2 sucks at that. I would also like the ability to fill in forms and navigate through button clicks.

Mostly the websites im interested in consist of a long list of results that load as you scroll down. Loading them all and then downloading the page doesnt seem to help(Dont know why that is). I'm using Windows 7, and have Python 2.7.5 installed.

I've been told that headless browsers such as zombie or Ghost would help me, but I really dont know much about those. I tried using libraries such as mechanize but they dont really cater for what I need, i.e, loading the results, fetching the webpage, and feeding into BS4.

Bearing in mind my minimal knowledge of Python, could anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: The Javascript will probably be fetching resources from some external JSON / XML / PHP Server. Use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to find out that source and then scrape from there.

Comment: I guess you're right about that but I was hoping of more of a generic solution to the problem, using headless browsers or some such

Comment: I don't know about that, sorry :(

Comment: I would not go very much in favor of Ghost. It is very limited and does not work for most websites.

Comment: Yes I tried Ghost and it wasnt very good

Answer (score 9):

[Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/) with [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/) can do headless automated browsing of JavaScript-driven webpages. Once installed, it can be used like this:

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import bs4 as bs

# define path to the phantomjs binary
phantomjs = 'phantomjs'
url = ...
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs)) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
```

---

On Ubuntu, they can be installed with

- `sudo pip install -U selenium`
- [Download and unpack phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)
- link or move the phantomjs binary to a directory in your PATH

  ```
  % cd phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-i686/bin/
  % ln phantomjs ~/bin
  ```

Comment: I was led to believe that PhantomJS had discontinued support for Python: http://phantomjs.org/release-1.5.html

Comment: @HamzaTahir, phantomjs itself has discontinued Python bindings, but a project called Ghostdriver https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver exists that provides a webdriver to Selenium to use PhantomJS as a browser. You can then use the Python bindings to control Selenium, which controls the webdriver which controls PhantomJS. Ghostdriver has since been merged upstream into Selenium.

Comment: @dilbert so I just need to use easy_install or pip to get Selenium, download the PhantomJS browser, and the above code will work?

Comment: Not quite, I needed to direct the webdriver to the PhantomJS binary and provide some other settings. Given I was also running multiple scrapers in parallel, I had to start the selenium server from Python aswell.

Comment: @dilbert: Were you using SeleniumRC? The newer Selenium webdriver does not require the selenium server.

Comment: @dilbert I downloaded Selenium using easy_install, extracted the phantomjs browser, and ran the  unutbu's code and it worked great! Awesome. Now I just need to learn how to load the JS and all

Comment: I'm running the "new" Selenium, but I had problems running the webdriver without starting the server first. I'm on Windows (Yay :P).

Comment: @HamzaTahir, when scraping dynamic content, you had to be mindful of timing, that is, the point at which the program should attempt to process the DOM to extract information. Depending on the structure of the site, this may be some time later (seconds) and attempting to load some expecting elements before they are existent (as they are dynamically created) will lead to problems.  Have a look at WebdriveWait (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917785/force-python-webdriver-to-wait-for-page-load) and expected_conditions.